# Java to Kotlin - Which datatype can handle an incoming ArrayTable<Integer,Integer,Integer> in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have this case in java -

```
ArrayTable<Integer, String, Object> x = someExternalService.someFunction(params);
```

How do i convert this to Kotlin? Which datatype should i use? I know writing datatypes isnt necessary, but still.

Comment: Why not just use the same data type? Is there any problem with using `ArrayTable` (I assume Guava's) in Kotlin?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to kotlin, didnt know we could use Java datatypes.

Comment: @DhruvChadha you can use almost any Java libraries and codebase in Kotlin. It is compatible with Java